# Identify this Super Mario Lego set

Tags: set-identification, super-mario

My son has a super mario LEGO set and we lost the box with the instructions in it. Can someone tell me what Super Mario Set this is?? [image: Super Mario pieces]

Answer (score 7):

These parts are from :

[1388: Boss Sumo Bro Topple](https://brickset.com/sets/71388-1/Boss-Sumo-Bro-Topple)
[image]

keyparts:

- [Blue Plate, Modified 6 x 6 with Rounded Corners and 4 Feet](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=66789#T=C)
- [Blue Brick 1 x 2 with Yellow Star with Black Eyes Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3004pb216#T=C&C=7)